# bash command to get href value down a specific class value

Tags: html, regex, bash, sed, grep

I'm new in shell scripting so I need some help. By shell script I need to get the value of a href property from a html filtered by the class.

eg:

`<a class="other class" href="value I don't need"></a>
<a class="some class" href="url I need"></a>`

In this case I need the href value of the a tag that got the class "some class".
I need to put the value into a variable, requires to use sed o grep, I'm not good with reggex at all so I need your help plz.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1032785)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way using `sed` and `grep`.

```
var=`grep 'class="some class"' <file> | sed -r 's/^.+href="([^"]+)".+$/\1/'`
```

First grep finds the right line, then the sed replaces the entire line with only the bracketed bit (which is the value of href).

Edit: if you have multiple `<a>` tags on one line, it gets a bit more tricky. If you can assume that the format of the tag is always like the examples, then you can try this:

```
var=`grep 'class="some class"' <file> | sed -r 's/^.+class="some class"\s+href="([^"]+)".+$/\1/'`
```

If you can't assume that (maybe sometimes the href comes before the class) then you're better off using an html parser - regex can't really parse html properly.

Comment: where I have to put the input file?

Comment: I tried but show blank results, the input file is a html file

Comment: ah sorry, it throughs blank result because in the line exist 2 <a> tag, that could break de process?

Comment: @dakairus No, it's because this command assigns the output to the variable called `var` because in your question you said that you needed to put it in a variable. After executing this line, execute `echo "$var"` to see your variable.

Comment: @dakairus although actually, if you have two `<a>` tags in one line it would cause issues. You won't get a blank result but you could get the wrong result since the first `grep` just finds the line and the second `sed` extracts the first `href` property it sees.

Comment: Your are right, sorry the issue was a because the "" '' characters in the body of the html, works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
awk -F'href="' '/class="some class/ {split($2,a,"\"");print a[1]}' file
url I need
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep 'some class'|sed -n 's/.*href="\(.*\)".*/\1/p'`

```
$ cat aaa
<a class="other class" href="value I don't need"></a>
<a class="some class" href="url I need"></a>

$ cat aaa|grep 'some class'|sed -n 's/.*href="\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
url I need
```